# Can I create a struct that can only be dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, struct, dangling-pointer

In C++, can I create a struct that can only be dynamically allocated? I want to enforce a way to make sure that the programmer cannot statically allocate this struct because doing so would lead to a dangling pointer since I need to use the contents of the pointer outside of its scope.

Comment: Don't allow them to make the struct themselves.  Have a function called make_X() that returns a pointer to X - kind of the same way make_shared() and make_unique() work.

Comment: You might consider a factory which _should_ be able to do what you want

Comment: Make the destructor `private`  (which will prevent it from being instantiated at all, except by a `friend` or a member function).    Then create a `static` and `public` member function of the class that dynamically creates an instance.   Bear in mind that only a member or a `friend` of the class can then destroy it.   It is possible to declare smart pointer types (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<your_type>`) as `friend`s, so they can destroy an object when needed.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean make the **con**structor private?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no, because there's only 1 destructor whereas maybe multiple constructors so it's easier to do the destructor

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - No I do not.   If the destructor is private, construction is prevented by any constructor (except by a `friend`  or member of the class).  I'll leave it for you to work out, as an exercise, why that is so.

Comment: @Peter but If the destructor is private, some functions won't do well. like the destructor of a smart ptr.

Comment: @asmmo - You clearly only read part of my previous comment.  I already addressed that.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the info. I'll look into that when I have some time to do some C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a `struct` of a private constructor so no one can create from it, then make a `friend` function that creat a dynamically allocated object and returns a pointer to it, as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "\nA has been destructed";
    }
private:
    A(/*args*/) {
        std::cout << "\nA has been created";
    }
    friend A* creatA(/*args*/);

};
A* creatA(/*args*/){
    return new A(/*args*/);
}

int main()
{
    A* ptr = creatA();
    delete ptr;

}
```

This can be better using smart pointers and @Peter suggestiion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A{
    A(/*args*/) {
        std::cout << "\nA has been created";
    }
    friend std::default_delete<A>;
private:
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "\nA has been destructed";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_unique<A>(/*Args*/);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@asmmo already explained but I want to offer similar solution in a more generalized way with `template`s. As far as I know, there is no language feature that makes the classes only be dynamically allocated. That means our desired behaviour should be mimicked. So the solution is to make the constructors only available for the functions which only allocates the classes dynamically.

Possible implementation :

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline T* create( Args&&... args )
{
    return new T { std::forward<Args>( args )... };
}

class foo
{
    private:
        foo() {}
        foo( int ) { }

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        friend T* create( Args&&... );
};

class bar
{
    private:
        bar() {}
        bar( int ) { }

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        friend T* create( Args&&... );
};

int main()
{
    auto f1 = create<foo>( 15 );
    auto f2 = create<foo>();
    auto b1 = create<bar>();
    auto b2 = create<bar>( 14 );
}
```

[run online](https://godbolt.org/z/4G96Yw)